# Почему  слово «надеть» иногда заменяют словом «одеть»?

Tags: словосочетания

1. Употребляя слова одеть-надеть, мы немного напрягаемся, выбирая правильный вариант. Существует даже условное правило: всегда говорите «надеть», потому что слово «одеть» невозможно употребить неправильно.  Например, можно только «одеть ребенка». Наш народ напрягаться не любит (и это справедливо), потому что речь должна быть естественно легкой и свободной, а в этом случае что-то этой легкости и свободе мешает. И возникает вопрос: только ли это условность нормы, или есть смысловое различие вариантов?
2. Предлагаемый ответ (как версия, минусы не ставьте) (смайлик):

2.1.  Приставка/предлог  О: обобщенное значение -  «вокруг». Приставка/предлог НА: обобщенное значение  - «на поверхность».

2.2. Надеть (что) на (кого/что) → надеть пальто  (на себя, на ребенка).

2.3. Одеть  (кого/реже что)  во (что)→

А) одеть ребенка (в пальто )→ одеть ребенка;
Б)  одеть (себя)  (в) пальто → одеть пальто.

2.4. В обоих случаях произошло упрощение форм, но по-разному, а в результате произошло сближение форм: одеть ребенка и одеть пальто.

2.5. Наши лингвисты воспринимают это сближение в штыки, заставляя «мучиться» бедный народ (смайлик). А вот почему всё-таки Достоевский это самое пальто «одевал»?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ.

В общем, я согласна с этими мыслями: облачать себя в одежду - это одевать, что не хуже варианта "надевать одежду на себя". Единственное, что еще неясно, - это когда и кто "запретил" одну из форм. Создается ощущение, что запрет был искусственным, - может быть. из желания показать свою "образованность" в части знания значений приставок О и НА.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 2.
Не стоит, наверное, сразу клеить ярлыки и клеймить "потомков Шариковых". Речь идет об истории вопроса и о разумном развитии языка, который должен быть удобным для пользователей, а вовсе не примитивным. И уровень его развития определяется разнообразием и прозрачностью предлагаемых форм речи, а совсем не их консерватизмом.  Почему классики употребляли форму "одеть" там, где нам разрешается только одна форма? Здесь уже были приведены интересные факты противостояния "одеть-надеть" в 19-20 веках , очень хотелось бы удлинить исторический экскурс, а также послушать дискуссии на эту тему в 18-19 веках.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 3.

Надо почитать дискуссию о снобизме в орфографии, я еще не в курсе прений. Но вот убеждение, что только «надеть пальто» – это правильно, я бы как раз отнесла к такому снобизму.  Мне кажется неверным смешивать «польта» и «надеть-одеть». В одном случае речь идет о развитии формы речи в определенном направлении, о существовании различных мнений по этому вопросу, в том числе у классиков, в другом – о нарушении общепризнанной нормы.  Не очень интересно  слушать лозунги, даже если они правильные.  Лучше сравните два варианта, дайте им оценку, проследите их историческое  развитие  и поделитесь с нами своими выводами. Конечно, это сложнее сделать, чем просто следовать заданной норме и  делить окружающих на грамотных и неграмотных.

Answer (score 6):

```
только ли это условность нормы, или есть смысловое различие вариантов?
```

Об этом спорят несколько поколений.Приставка о– (об-) может обозначать распространение действия вокруг предмета. 
на- – положение на поверхности предмета: нагорье, нагрудник, наконечник, наплечник, нарукавник, наручник, наушник; Следовательно: **Одеть Надежду - надеть одежду.**

Указанное различие в семантике глаголов одеть и надеть характеризует нормативное употребление, сложившееся в русском литературном языке первой половины XIX в.
В настоящее время глагол одеть нередко употребляется вместо глагола надеть. Некоторыми лингвистами  такое употребление характеризуется как грубое нарушение норм литературного словоупотребления.
Такой пуризм другие лингвисты не оправдывают, поскольку речевая практика уже в течение более трех столетий расходится с нормативными предписаниями, идущими, кстати, еще от «Справочного места русского языка» А. Греча
 Справочное мѣсто русскаго слова: четыреста пятьдесят поправок, с руководством к употреблению буквы Ѣ    
http://avva.livejournal.com/2549628.html

Об этом же: http://trworkshop.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=55&t=43218

Может,  в данном случае работает аналогия с "обуть":

Надеть на ноги (какую-л. обувь). Старик обул валенки. Зачем ты опять обула выходные туфли? // Разг. Проф.(с сайта Грамота.ру)
Вариант "набуть" вряд ли  употребляется, и, возможно, этот факт "тянет за собой" также и разговорную сочетаемость слова "одеть".

Эти глаголы имеют общий корень и обозначают по сути  одно и то же, а грамматические правила употребления их всегда были разными. Когда утратилась связь между приставкой и  свойственным лишь ей предлогом(надеть на что-то, надеть на голову, но одеть во что-то - одеть одежду),возникал соблазн все дело свести только к одному одеть, как к наиболее простой форме: эти попытки в разговорном речи  были известны с начала 19в., в литературном языке с 20 в.

С 50-х гг. 20в. опять возникло стремление эти глаголы различать.Но вот у Ожегова:  Одеть кого,во что- покрыть кого-нибудь какой-нибудь одеждой, покрывалом;

Надеть что. 1. Укрепить что-н. на чём-н., прикрепить, приладить что-н. к чему-н. Н. кольцо на палец.  2. Покрыть тело или часть тела какой-н. одеждой. Н. шубу. Н. пальто на ребёнка.

Определения-то(2 значение)почти одинаковые. Вот они и восприняты как синонимы, а не паронимы.

И разговорная речь делала свое. В 1973 г.  впервые разрешено разговорной речи употреблять эти  глаголы безразлично.

Сейчас одеть связывается со словом одежда, а глагол надеть - нет. Лишь глагол одеть может выступать в переносном значении, а глагол надеть – никогда.
http://gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti/36_119

Но это в науке, а в разговорной речи это не учитывается. Может, скоро паронимы станут синонимами и в литературном языке, как, например СМИРИТЬСЯ( недавно слово смириться имело значение «стать смирным, покорным, смиренным»; употребление его в значении «примириться» считалось недопустимым. Однако в разговорной речи это слово все чаще стало обозначать – «привыкнув, примириться с чем-нибудь»: смириться с бедностью, смириться с недостатками. Современные толковые словари русского языка (например, Ожегов, Шведова, 1999, с. 519) отмечают это значение как основное, бывшие паронимы стали синонимами).

Answer (score 3):

Одеть что-нибудь на кого-то/что-то = одеть кого-то/что-то во что-нибудь = одеться во что-нибудь.

> Максим Горький. Фома Гордеев (1899)
> Она ... убрала стол старинным серебром, **одела шелковое платье** цвета стали и, сидя перед зеркалом, стала вдевать в уши огромные изумруды...
> П. Н. Краснов. От Двуглавого Орла к красному знамени (книга 2) (1922)
> Я продала все мои бриллианты, меха и платья, я продала все, что имела, я **оделась в платье простой крестьянки**, которое купила в Перелесине...

*Одеть платье на себя* (одеться в платье) или *одеть ребенка в платье* - нет никакой разницы, процесс одевания идентичен самому себе, сколько бы ни трепались на эту тему "знатоки" русского языка.

> В. М. Дорошевич. Сахалин (Каторга) (1903) Я ей и кофточку подал. Одела {кофточку} она, застегнулась. «Принесите, ― говорит, ― кассу сюда, она не тяжелая».
>
> Андрей Белый. Кубок метелей (1907)   Игуменья расплела шелковые ткани кудрей, **одела серебристый клобук**, обвила себя атласом лилейным, собираясь к нему на встречу.

Примеры из литературы (десятки, сотни примеров), взятые в Нацкорпусе, благополучно подтверждают обычную мысль : предметы верхней одежды (то есть не белья!) и головные уборы (реже обувь) "надевают и одевают" без всякого запрета, руководствуясь собственным чувством языка. **Одежду с рукавами или штанинами** - почему бы не **одеть** на себя??  Не только одеждой одевают, но и одежду - одевают, на себя или кого-то, в этих действиях нет никакого противоречия :

> Вадим Сидур. Памятник современному состоянию (1973-1974)  ― **Жархалаты под гимнастерки одевайте** и в шаровары заправляйте.

Сравните глагол **одевать/одеть** с глаголом **убивать/убить**. Можно убивать (кого?) зверей, можно убивать (чем?) рогатиной, можно убивать (за что?) за предательство. Широкие смысловые связи, не правда ли? Чего же ради глаголу одеть/одевать "разрешены" связи *кого и во что?*, но "запрещены" связи *что и на кого?*... Облачить кого в одежду - только *одеть*, в этом вопросе никто и никогда не ошибается, потому что надеть человека можно только на кол, если заслужил, конечно.  Именно этот момент и отметила Новелла Матвеева в своих шутливых стихах.
Мелкие вещички (белье, кольца, браслеты, пояса, шарфы, варежки, перчатки и пр.) - только надевают, как правило, хотя вполне возможны и здесь какие-то исключения (?), подробно этот вопросик еще не изучил. Впрочем, вот :

> В. М. Дорошевич. Сахалин (Каторга) (1903) Вы это поскорей **платочек и фартучек одевайте**.

Answer (score 0):

Подобные упрощения начали появляться после Октябрьской революции, когда начали искоренять исконно русскую интеллигенцию как класс. В 50-х годах 20 века была попытка исправить положение. Но, к сожалению, потомки "Шариковых" продолжают диктовать свои условия. А вообще-то это 2-й класс общеобразовательной школы. Ну что ж, давайте больше не будем "мучить бедный народ" и позволим говорить, например, "звОнит", заодно уж... :-) И это еще только для начала!

Comment: Это далеко не начало (раньше говорили *набувать* и *катИт*), и вряд ли это конец. Единственное почему *звОнит* до сих пор не стало нормой, это языковой снобизм интеллигенции, структуре языка слово не противоречит.

Answer (score 0):

В народе и дальше будут продолжать говорить "звонит", "ложит", "одевать польта" и кофе будет все равно "оно". Ну да Бог с ними, с простыми людьми, значит учителя у них были хреновыми (пардон за выражение). Но когда все это прёт в печатные издания и на ТВ, вылетает изо рта известных людей типа с высшим образованием, это уже, мягко говоря, очень сильно расстраивает!

Comment: Кофе -- оно уже давно разрешили официально, вы заскорузли в своем педантизме.

Answer (score 0):

Шариковы -- не те, кто путает одеть/надеть. Шариковы -- это вроде этих: https://youtu.be/r_lAr21vv98
Загрызут, ревнители правил, и не подавятся.