# Правильное употребление слов

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте! Недавно узнала, что надо "аккуратнее" употреблять глаголы одеть и надеть,т.к. одеть/раздеть -относится к живым существам, а надеть/снять -к неодушевленным предметам. Какими правилами (или алгоритмами) надо руководствоваться, чтобы не запутаться.С уважением Тата.

Answer (score 1):

Какими правилами... Вы же их сами описали: одеть/раздеть живое существо, надеть/снять неодушевленные предметы (т.е. одежду в нашем случае). Вот и вся премудрость.

Лирическое отступление... Я считаю, что "одеть пальто" лет через 30, а то и раньше, станет допустимым разговорным -- уж больно многие так говорят. Я и сам так говорю. )))

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая "запоминалка":

*Надеть одежду, одеть Надежду.*

Надевают что-то на кого-то, а одевают кого-то.

Comment: А вы не подскажете, откуда взялось это правило? Вот в 19 веке вполне интеллигентные люди позволяли себе "одевать" пальто.

Answer (score 0):

Эмпирическое правило для говорящего:если возможны две формы произношения надеть/одеть, то следует сказать "надеть", и тогда вы не ошибетесь. Но чтобы оценить правильность чужой речи, этого правила недостаточно.

Этот вопрос уже обсуждался:

[Почему  слово «надеть» иногда заменяют словом «одеть»?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/26902/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C)