# Почему Окуджава одевает, а не надевает плащ?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, глаголы, паронимы

**У Б. Окуджавы есть прекрасное стихотворение**, в котором он говорит о любви, о людях, о философии жизни:

```
 Дождусь я лучших дней и новый плащ ОДЕНУ,
 чтоб пред тобой проплыть, как поздний лист, кружа...
 Не много ль я хочу, всему давая цену?
 Не сладко ль я живу, тобой лишь дорожа?
```

**[В песне](https://yandex.ru/video/preview/4164123222222905860)** поется именно так, но можно найти исправленный текст ― **надену!**

**Тема не нова,** обсуждалась часто. Но вот захотелось взглянуть на нее в новом году по-новому: откуда у нас берутся заповеди "говори только так, а иначе ты нарушаешь нормы русской речи и не чтишь  культуру языка".

**[На другом сайте](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4321764-2-tipa-ljudej-vy-nadevaete-ili-odevaete-odezhdu.html)** был задан интересный вопрос: **Два типа людей. Вы надеваете или одеваете одежду?** Одни тщательно следят за правильностью употребления "надеть-одеть", а другие не видят разницы. Вы в каком лагере?

Также мне попалось еще **[одно обсуждение](https://vk.com/wall11566647_4557)**: Скажите, откуда взялся общепринятый стандарт **"надеть на кого-то, одеть кого-то"?** Почти все писатели XX века употребляли "одеть" в значении "надеть". Окуджава, например, пел, что лучший плащ оденет.

А еще можно заглянуть на наш форум в 2013 год (**как раз десятилетний юбилей**) и послушать **[наших участников](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/26902/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C):** Почему слово «надеть» иногда заменяют словом «одеть»?

Ну и вопрос: Почему Окуджава и другие классики **нарушают общепринятую норму?** Это с ними что-то не так или с нами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Моя история с "одеть-надеть" началась точно после школы. Может, кто-то поправил меня – не помню. В любом случае объяснение разницы между этими глаголами показалось мне логичным, и я очень быстро встроил эту парадигму в свою речь. Со "зво́нит", кстати, похоже было.
И что странно – чем дальше я становлюсь грамотнее (в кавычках), тем больше спотыкаюсь, акцентируя внимание на несущественном. Какая, например, разница, куда мы поставим ударение в слове "одновре́ме́нно"? Мелодия речи может выбрать сама, а смысл никак не пострадает.
"Метро" из мужского рода стало средним вроде безболезненно (или я не застал те времена?), а вот "кофе" в наших ушах ещё сопротивляется.
Всем хочется и всем нравится говорить грамотно, правильно. Но язык сам устанавливает текучие правила, и удел тех, кто его описывает, – фиксировать "среднюю температуру по палате".
Ведь нормально же сидели: всем всё было понятно, все вокруг говорили "одеть"... И тут появляется "грамотный" и разрушает идиллию. Терпимее надо быть, добрее.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я помню, мы с вами обсуждали одеть/надеть, и вы выглядели   фанатом нормы)  А мне вот зонИт в голову вбили,  а одеть/надеть не успели. В "одновременно" вроде два ударения разрешают. Кофе у меня только черный, а  для метро вроде бы м.род допускался: "Hо метро сверкнул перилами дубовыми. Сразу всех он седоков околдовал".   Но это уже стало историей. Вы правы, надо быть терпимее и добрее, разрешать обе нормы, если для этого есть основания. А то ведь действительно,  делают из одной формы религиозный культ и требуют поклонения.

Comment: @Sharon Хорошо сказано!

Comment: А я терпим к одеть/надеть, но кофе среднего рода не приемлю. Это для слабаков, как я привык говорить.

Answer (score 1):

Так как тема не нова, то желательно сказать что-то **новое**, а не повторяться.

1. Я из тех людей, которые не напрягаются при выборе формы, но, как мне думается, к варианту ***"одеть"*** отношусь **более благосклонно.** Почему? Вероятно, я учитываю такие слова, как ***"одеться"*** (как бы одеть в одежду себя), а также само слово ***"одежда"***. Все они с приставкой ***О***, а приставка ***НА*** выглядит как частный вариант в этой теме.
2. И вот что еще важно: **я не люблю слушаться.** А норма ― это всегда послушание. Конечно, есть нормы языка, по отношению к которым в обществе нет колебания (только пальто, например). Если же существует достаточное количество **вариантов**, то лучше не слушаться, а подумать.

И тогда я решаю: с нормой и ее фанатами я спорить **не буду**, но постараюсь в свободной обстановке  говорить так, как мне **нравится**. А учитывая, что писатели использовали форму "одеть", я считаю ее для себя **вполне приемлемой.**

3. Что касается самого **послушания**, то к нему отношусь отрицательно. Вроде бы мелочи (надеть, а не одеть), но на этой **однозначной** норме для всех отрабатывается **привычка** слушаться. У такого человека несвободное мышление: он не сделает новых открытий ни в одной из областей человеческой деятельности.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

На практике я использую оба варианта: ***одеть и надеть***. В комментариях это обсуждалось, и можно предположить, что выбор носители языка делают **по ситуации.** Как мне думается, форма ***надеть*** подчеркивает **праздничность**: *Одену – это одеть обычную, повседневную одежду. А надеть – это торжественно, это одеть что-то новое, праздничное.* **Или не так?**

Но вот в книге **Наринэ Абгарян "Манюня"**  я нахожу подтверждение этой точки зрения:

*Собирала меня мама в гости как на Судный день. С утра она собственноручно выкупала меня так, что вместе с кожей сошла часть скудной мышечной массы. Потом она туго заплела мне косички...моя неземная красота требовала жертв, поэтому я стоически выдержала все процедуры. **Затем мне дали НАДЕТЬ новое летнее платье — нежно-кремовое, с рукавами-буф и кружевным подолом.***

*— Поставишь пятно — выпорю, — ласково предупредила мама, — твоим сестрам еще донашивать платье за тобой.*

*Она торжественно вручила мне пакет с нашим семейным альбомом и коробкой конфет для Ба.*

Comment: Действительно, я бы сказал, что одеть стало уже стало узусом. У меня самого порой вылетает одеть вместо надеть. Почему Окуджава пел одеть вместо надеть сказать трудно.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж. Вероятно, он не считал эту норму обязательной, не видел в ее соблюдении какой-то особой культуры. Или плохо выучил: одеть Надежду – надеть одежду)  Другой вариант: может в его время не было особой строгости для этой нормы.

Comment: А какого года эта песня? Скорее всего он, как вы верны заметили,  не считал эту норму обязательной. А может, специально пел, показывая, что не считает правильным соблюдать норму.

Comment: Об этом говорил и Микитко, и филолог писала в Аргументах и фактах. Постараюсь дать ссылку.

Comment: Я нашла:  Стихотворение, 1972 год  https://fantlab.ru/work567287  Слова иногда разные: дрожа/кружа, туш/гимн.

Comment: В одной статье: Я не понимаю содержания песни! А дальше – всякие домыслы. А я хорошо понимаю, ну очень ясно.

Answer (score 1):

В общем я подумал) и скажу, что приставка О- не всегда приставка Об-.
Скорее всего это отдельная приставка, но может быть и синонимичная с об-.

Например, оделить - обделить - два противоположных варианта. Омыть - обмыть, омыть - сделать чистым, обмыть - смыть грязь. Приставка Об - связана со внешним воздействием, приставка О- имеет значение наделение качеством чего-то, то есть не внешняя перемена, а внутреннее преображение. Обмыть - обделать, отметить; омыть, омовение - религиозное или духовное принятие, достижение чистоты. Отопить - сделать тёплым, отопить дом, обтопить - партитивное, обтопить сало по краям, обжарить, окопать - сделать копанным, обкопать - перекопать вокруг, но не внутри. Окупить, окупиться - возместить, обкупаться, обкупиться - ошибиться в рассчетах, отдать лишнее. То есть О- о принятии качества, свойства, Об- о потере. Обежать можно вокруг себя глазами, а [оббежать](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/283750#)(разговорное) можно только дом кругом, то есть бегая вокруг чего-то. Ну и, наконец, ожить - преисполниться жизнью, а обжить - наполнить своей жизнью пространство. Омереть - "Впасть в летаргич. сон (Каз., Веш., Рзд.)", обмереть - испугаться, перестать двигаться, околеть - умереть совсем). Омелье - мелкие отходы от помола муки. А река - обмелевшая, то есть причастие отглагольное. Очистить - привнести чистоту, наделить чистотой, обчистить - унести всё под чистую, оставить лишь чистоту. То есть тут имеет место быть соперничество между качеством и внутренним наполнением и глаголом действия на объект-предмет, без нарушения внутренней структуры, это и отражено в приставках О- и Об-.

Касательно же надеть - это выражение партитивного действия не с целым, а счастью. Надеть сапог на ногу - обуть сапог, обуться сапогом. Либо увеличить уже качество или свойство - натопить, то есть сделать тёплое еще теплее. Надел корону на голову, точно не одел, надел кольцо на палец.

Оделять - давать, дарить подарки, наделять - передавать части чего-то, что-то по частям, наделы, обделять - не давать)

Что же касательно "новый плащ ОДЕНУ", тут я не могу согласиться, потому что нельзя наполниться плащом, но можно наполниться новым, принять новое, поэтому говорят "одену новое платье" - одену новое и платье, оденусь новым, то есть. Но новый - уже прилагательное относящееся к плащу, его не переделать в новое или новым. Оденусь новым плащом? В общем тут не уверен, форма слова не совсем подходит, хотя Окуджава любил писать песни от женского лирического образа, может тут есть с этим путаница...

Хотя, может и не так, а ОДЕЛ имеет значение нарядился, украсился, оделся во что-то специально - преобразился. Обычно одел пишут об особых нарядах, а не о будничных деталях гардероба.

> Он одел перчатки на руки и обернул тряпками сапоги, чтобы не оставить после себя следов.  Раскрытие кражи из заготовления государственных бумаг (12.11.1911) // «Речь», 1911.

> Он принял ванну, причем, вопреки обыкновению, очень деликатно выругал матроса только скотиной и подлой душой, одел все чистое, хотел даже надушиться, но совсем забыл, как это делается, да и совестно стало. Тэффи.

Плюс одел-одела - фразы сказанные с самоотрешением:

> Не понимаю! Учился — носил мундир дворянского института... а чему учился? Не помню... Женился — одел фрак, потом — халат... а жену взял скверную и — зачем? Не понимаю... Прожил все, что было, — носил какой-то серый пиджак и рыжие брюки... а как разорился? ..
> Служил в казенной палате... мундир, фуражка с кокардой... растратил казенные деньги, — **надели на меня** арестантский халат... потом — **одел вот это**... И всё... как во сне... а? Это... смешно? Сатин.
> Горький. На дне.

Comment: Приставка О обозначает действие, которое охватывает весь предмет; притом она чаще применяется в книжной речи или используется в переносном значении. Приставка ОБ имеет аналогичное значение, то есть приставка также обозначает действие, которое охватывает весь предмет, но  чаще используется в прямом (конкретном) смысле и в разговорной речи. Отереть пот с лица и оттирать грязь с одежды – приставки О и ОТ; обивать пороги и оббивать дверь – приставки О и ОБ; обежать стадион, обежать все магазины, обежать взглядом – приставка О, также возможно: оббежать стадион (приставка ОБ, разг. стиль).

Comment: Теперь о приставке О в слове одеть. Мне кажется, что она более уместна,  чем приставка НА. Значение здесь переносное  для действия, которое охватывает весь предмет. Именно охватывает, а не обхватывает. А приставка НА  конкретная, да еще в узком значении (действие   направлено на что-либо).  Интересная пара:  надели на меня арестантский халат... потом — одел вот это...

Comment: Правильное управление: надеть НА. Тогда как: будем все одевать?

Comment: @Sharon ну понятно, что хотел сказать Окуджава и акцент там на "новым" а не на плащ, стану новым, обновлённым, вновь красивым - проплыву как поздний лист кружа в последнем прощальном танце.  Я не уверен, что так прямо можно, но если бы он сказал новый плащ надену - то было бы грубовато, да, не совсем то. О - имеет больше образное значение. Отереть пот - передохнуть, а оттереть пот или грязь - это конкретное действие с отиранием частиц. Об - партитивная приставка.

Comment: @Sharon а тут не управление, а наполнение - преисполниться новым, свежим. О - о внутреннем наполнении, а не об- внешнем отделении.

Comment: Все верно, нет вопросов, образная приставка.

Comment: Может, Окуджава не хотел ничем наполняться.  У него одеть – в переносном значении. Еще есть: Я много лет пиджак ношу, давно потерся и не новый.

Comment: @Sharon согласен, что это всё метафоры, а не указание одежды. Также может быть О- также происходит от ОТ- - одел в смысле отдал качество, отдал что-то. Оделил - дал подарки. Одел - дал вещь и тут важно кто, а не что. Государь одел войско по образцу войска - государь одел, а не одел войско по образцу.  я опять его одел(Герцен) акцент на Я, то есть не его одел, а Я-одел, но его. Поэтому тут скорее не управление. Надену колец, но одену(сь) (в)  украшения, одену украшений.

Comment: То есть последнее неверно) одену украшений не верно). Окуплю покупки, но накуплю покупок. Либо творительный падеж - оделю подарками, окуплю поездкой/поездку, но не поездок.

Comment: @Sharon в общем я запутался)

Comment: А знаете, я стала этот стих читать, и читаю на автомате  – надену. Обратила на это внимание – думаю, а почему? И вот что мне показалось. Одену –  это одеть обычную, повседневную одежду. А надеть – это торжественно, это одеть что-то новое, праздничное.  Стилистика?

Comment: Одену– это обычную, повседневную одежду. А надеть – это торжественно, это что-то новое, праздничное. - мне наоборот показалось) мистика)

Comment: Это мистическая стилистика, ага?  Нужно опросить общество по этой теме.